# undefined reference on lib.a with symbol in the lib

Tags: linker, g++, static-libraries

I'm new in managing lib, so I want to understand why I recieved an

`libcrypto.a(e_aesgcmsiv.c.o):e_aesgcmsiv.c:(.text+0x1a4) : undefined reference to « aes128gcmsiv_aes_ks »`

when I link my executable with libcrypto.a

For checking what is in my libcrypto.a I try to nm the static lib and I see this things (in this order) :

```
aes128gcmsiv-x86_64.asm.o:
0000000000000510 T aes128gcmsiv_aes_ks
...
000000000000051d t L$SEH_begin_aes128gcmsiv_aes_ks
...
00000000000005f5 t L$SEH_end_aes128gcmsiv_aes_ks

e_aesgcmsiv.c.o:
...
000000000000159f t aead_aes_gcm_siv_seal_scatter
                 U aes_ctr_set_key
                 U aes128gcmsiv_aes_ks
...
```

So if I understand correctly, my libcrypto.a contains in aes128gcmsiv-x86_64.asm.o the function aes128gcmsiv_aes_ks.
And in e_aesgcmsiv.c.o I would to use the function which is undefined in the scope of this .o file.
But because everything is in my lib I can't understand why I recieved an undefined reference.

If it could help the file e_aesgcmsiv.c contains this :

```
extern void aes128gcmsiv_aes_ks(
    const uint8_t key[16], uint8_t out_expanded_key[16*15]);
```

And later it use the function.

PS : I don't paste the asm file that contains the real code of the function but I think it's not revelant cause you can see that it's present in the lib.

EDIT : I find a workaround (I link the aes128gcmsiv-x86_64.asm.o file before my libcrypto.a, with that the function is known).
But It's not the answer to my question : why it doesn't work automatically with all informations in the lib.a

Comment: Your question requires a lot of additional details: what is your link line? Which library (path) did you run `nm` on, and how do you know that's the library actually used during the link? Most likely you have two versions of `libcrypto.a`, and are using wrong version during the actual link.

Comment: Well play !!! there is a libcrypto.a in my OS and a libcrypto.a in the project. I suppose that the OS version is used and not contains the needed function.
Thanks @EmployedRussian